# Array list for sprites in android game/app

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, sprite

I'm trying to get more than one sprite on screen (two for now to see if I can get it going) but all it does is just display the one still.
My code is as follows (it's all in one class:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

/* Member (state) fields   */
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object
/** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
// For creating the game Sprite
private Sprite sprite;
//For multiple sprites
private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;
// For recording the number of hits
private int hitCount;
// For displaying the highest score
//private int highScore;
// To track if a game is over
private boolean gameOver;
// To play sound
private SoundPool mySound;
// Zap sound when sprite hit
int zapSoundId;

int count = 2;
int arraySize;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
    this.setFocusable(true);
    // For intercepting events on the surface.
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // Background image added
    mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.castle);
    // Initialise sprites object
    spritesArrayList = new ArrayList<Sprite>();







}
/* Called immediately after the surface created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        spritesArrayList.add(sprite);
    }
    // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
    ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
    gameLoopThread.running = true;
    gameLoopThread.start();
}



// For the countdown timer
private long startTime; // Timer to count down from
private final long interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 sec interval
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // Reference to the class
private boolean timerRunning = false;
private String displayTime; // To display the time on the screen


public void getArrayListSize() {
    if (spritesArrayList.isEmpty()) {
        // nothing
    } else {
        arraySize = spritesArrayList.size();
    }
}

//To initialise/reset game
private void ResetGame() {
    /* Set paint details */
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    hitCount = 0;
    // Set timer
    startTime = 10; // Start at 10s to count down
    // Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime * 1000, interval);
    countDownTimer.start(); // Start the time running
    timerRunning = true;
    gameOver = false;


}

// Countdown Timer - private class
private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //displayTime = "Time is up!";
        timerRunning = false;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        gameOver = true;
    }
    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
        displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
    }
}


//This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
public void update() {
    if (gameOver != true) {
        spritesArrayList.clear();
        sprite.update();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < spritesArrayList(); i++) {
        sprite = new Sprite(this);
        spritesArrayList.add(sprite);
    }
}



private int spritesArrayList() {
    return 0;
}



/*private void createSprites() {
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad3));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.bad4));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good2));
    sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.good5));
}*/

/*private Sprite createSprite(int resource) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);

    return new Sprite(this, bmp);
}*/
/**
 * To draw the game to the screen
 * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
 */
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceAsColor")
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Draw all the objects on the canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    getArrayListSize();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        Sprite sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
        sprite.draw(canvas);
    }

        if (!gameOver) {

            sprite.draw(canvas);
            paint.setColor(R.color.red);
            canvas.drawText("Time Remaining: " + displayTime, 35, 50, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Number of hits: " + hitCount, 250, 50, paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawText("Game Over!", 185, 100, paint);
            canvas.drawText("To go back to the main menu, press the 'back' key", 15, 150, paint);
        }

}

//To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
        sprite = new Sprite(this);
        hitCount++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    gameLoopThread.running = false;

    // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public int getHitCount() {

    return hitCount;

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}


}
```

If anyone would like me to clarify any of the code, please let me know.

Thanks